# Blank Areas in the Corner When Filling Brushes into Rectangles Shape

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, rectangles, brush

No matter how I tried, there are blank areas in the corner when I try to fill in my brush which is created in `ResourceDictionary`. I tired `Stretch = Fill`, `Uniform`, and `UniformToFill`. None of them worked.

Comment: Could you perhaps show us that XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you used transform rotation in your code. If you want to fill in a rectangle area. You must use rectangle shape brush instead of diamond or any other brush in shape other than rectangle. PS: rotated rectangle brushes may fill in ellipse, but will leave some blank for other shapes like polygon.